# Get chatGPT to respond with a single direct answer

Tags: python, nlp, openai-api, langchain, chat-gpt-4

I am querying a text using chatGPT. But I need chatGPT to respond with single direct answers, rather than long stories or irrelevant text. Any way to achieve this?

My code looks like:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import DocArrayInMemorySearch
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator

loader = TextLoader("path/to/extracted_text.txt")
loaded_text = loader.load()
# Save document text as vector.
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(
            vectorstore_cls=DocArrayInMemorySearch
        ).from_loaders([loader])

# Query the text
response = index.query("At what time did john come home yesterday?")
print("Loaded text is:", loaded_text)
print("ChatGPT response is:", response)
```

> >>> Loaded text is: "< a really long text > + John came home last
> night at 11:30pm + < a really long text >"

> >>> ChatGPT response is: "John came back yesterday at 11:30pm."

The problem is that I want a concise answer `11:30pm` rather than a full sentence `John came home last night at 11:30pm`. Is there a way to achieve this without adding "I need a short direct response" to my query? Can I achieve a more guaranteed concise response by setting a parameter through some other means instead?

Comment: This comes down to prompt engineering and is therefore not programming and therefore off-topic. You need to wait for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463/starting-the-prompt-design-site-a-new-home-in-our-stack-exchange-neighborhood?cb=1

Comment: what luk2302 said, but also, asking, "how can I get a generative AI to do a thing without telling it to do the thing" is quite a strange question. ChatGPT can't read your mind

Comment: Perhaps, that is the reason for the downvotes. The problem is that I do not want to take the prompt engineering route, hence the reason why I have posted this question. I felt perhaps someone would offer an alternative means to let me tune a parameter like the temperature, top_k, set_top_p, etc... Been going through the docs but found nothing yet. @luk2302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *ONLY* way to achieve what you want is **Proper Prompt Engineering**.  Period.  No way around it.  It's more of a thought discipline than acquiring a new skill.  Read [this quick Microsoft Learn doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/concepts/advanced-prompt-engineering?pivots=programming-language-chat-completions) about prompt engineering to privy yourself to the knowledge you need to advance your task.  Best wishes!

Comment: Thanks. I just needed someone to prove to me that there was no other way but through prompt engineering. I found the link really helpful. Thanks.